# How to obtain Checkbox values ( checked by user) using ng-model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

While trying to implement Checkbox functionality,I am not able to obtain which checkboxes the user has selected. How is this done?
Below is my HTML snippet:

```
<td>
                <table border="0"><th>Tier</th>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in tiertype">             
                    <td>
                    <label class="checkbox" for="{{item.id}}">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.ids[item.id]" name="tier_class" ng-checked="item.checked" id="{{item.id}}"/>{{item.name}}
                    </label>
                    </td></tr></table>
            </td>
```

And below is my javascript snippet:

```
$scope.tiertype = [ 
                       { id: 1, name: "All", checked: true}, 
                       { id: 2, name: "Standard", checked: false },
                       { id: 3, name: "Unreserved", checked: false },
                       { id: 3, name: "Reserved", checked: false },
                       { id: 4, name: "General", checked: false }
                       ];
```

Iam not getting proper values on using "check box value= {{selection.ids}}". Moreover, on checking any checbox, all are getting checked or the checbox with id:1 (default).
Seems strange to me, not able to figure out. Where am I going wrong as I dont have much experience in AngularJS.

Comment: Change your ngModel to `ng-model="item.checked"`

Comment: I've put together a jsFiddle that should help .
[Checkbox Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/t7kr8/) The key is using a directive.

Comment: one problem of all checkboxes getting checked etc got solved by this but How can i know on the js side using scope etc to know which checkboxes were checked by user?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the checkbox ng-model to the boolean value for the check.  IE: ng-model="item.checked"

Comment: ng-model ="item.checked" enables default check on 1st option but on doing "values checked by user: {{checked}}" or {{item.checked}}, doesnot return anything. How would i come to know which checkboxes were checked by user?